# Dataframe to Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to convert it into a dictionary. I looked at 10 articles and they do not seem to have what I am asking for.

```
Dataframe:
         Count
Item
Coke     531
Sprite   432
Redbull  225
Monster  124

Output:
{Coke:531, Sprite:432, Redbull:225, Monster:124}
```

Comment: Use `d = df['Count'].to_dict()`